# Laravel inner with another table and condition

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm using laravel and I have two tables (users) and (logs) I want to select all users that has at least one log between January 2017 and December 2018 every time a user visit web site with his account it's count 1 log; I did one query but it's return duplicate on my results, I did use distinct but no difference.

my query is :

```
$query = Member::where('members.create_date', '>=', $date_start->startOfDay())
                ->whereNotIn('members.id', [3, 7, 10])
                ->where('members.langue', '=', 'en')
                ->where('members.age', '>', 17)
                ->where('members.level', '>', 5)
                ->join('user_logs', 'members.id', '=', 'user_log.member_id')
                ->where('user_logs.date', '>=', $date_log_start->startOfDay())
                ->where('user_logs.date', '<=', $date_log_end->endOfDay())
                ->orderBy('members.id', 'DESC')
        ;

$members = $query->get();
```

I have function UserLogs

```
public function userlogs()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Http\Models\UserLogs', 'membre_id');
}
```

Comment: Do you have *eloquent relationship* set up on Member and Log model?

Comment: I update my question to add a function userlogs that hasMany

Answer (score 0):

when you do not use 'select' the default behavior is selecting all (*) ...
to resolve this determine the columns you want to select, then use 'distinct':

```
$query = Member::where('members.create_date', '>=', $date_start->startOfDay())
                ->whereNotIn('members.id', [3, 7, 10])
                ->where('members.langue', '=', 'en')
                ->where('members.age', '>', 17)
                ->where('members.level', '>', 5)
                ->join('user_logs', 'members.id', '=', 'user_log.member_id')
                ->where('user_logs.date', '>=', $date_log_start->startOfDay())
                ->where('user_logs.date', '<=', $date_log_end->endOfDay())
                ->orderBy('members.id', 'DESC')
                ->select('members.id','members.level') // select your columns 
                ->distinct();
```

Comment: I'm still getting same result that return duplicate users

Comment: what are the column you select?

Comment: all the column of member table